# Assimp Skinning Global Transforms

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, assimp, skeletal-animation

I'm currently implementing Skeletal Animation into my 3D OpenGL Game Engine using the ASSIMP library, unfortunately it isn't going all that great.
The problem I am currently facing is that the concatenated bone transforms (the parent-child relationship between bones) only act correctly when only one parent is being transformed.

What happens is that the [thigh's bone transformation is carried out on global axes instead of the pelvis' local axes.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1s3fdBfVZo&feature=youtu.be)

Here is my Skeleton class:

```
class Skeleton
{
public:
    Skeleton();

    unsigned int numBones;
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    std::vector<glm::mat4> offsets;


    std::vector<glm::mat4> transforms;
    std::vector<int> parents;

    std::string GetName(int bone);
    glm::mat4 GetWorldTransform(int bone);
    int GetID(std::string bone_name);
};
```

and here is the function I use to calculate the world transform for each bone:

```
glm::mat4 Skeleton::GetWorldTransform(int bone)
{
int p = parents[bone];
glm::mat4 result = glm::mat4(1.0);

result *= glm::inverse(offsets[bone]);
    result *= transforms[bone];
result *= offsets[bone];

while(p >= 0)   //The root bone has a parent of -1
{
    result *= glm::inverse(offsets[p]);
        result *= transforms[p];    //Apply The Parent's Transform
    result *= offsets[p];

    p = parents[p];
}
return result;
}
```

And in my Mesh class I have this function UpdateSkeleton():

```
void Mesh::UpdateSkeleton(unsigned int shaderID)
{
std::vector<glm::mat4> mats;

for(int i = 0; i < skeleton->numBones; i++)
{
    glm::mat4 matrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
        matrix *= skeleton->GetWorldTransform(i);
    mats.push_back(matrix);
}

if(mats.size() > 0)
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderID,"gBones"),mats.size(),GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(mats[0]));
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So I fixed it.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLi9hkiiZDonvUcT_FRD8rJtuuGltL3xys

Basically the problem was that the concatenations were being done in the reverse order, I was doing them like this originally:

```
void Bone::UpdateParentTransform()
{
    parent_transform = glm::mat4(1.0);

    Node* node_id = parent_node;

    while(node_id != nullptr)
    {
        Bone* bone = mesh->FindBone(node_id->name);

        if(bone != nullptr)
        {
            parent_transform *= glm::inverse(bone->offset_matrix);
                parent_transform *= node_id->transformation;
            parent_transform *= (bone->offset_matrix);
            node_id = bone->parent_node;
        }
        else
            node_id = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Now I made it so they are performed in the reverse order, like so:

```
void Bone::UpdateParentTransform()
{
    parent_transform = glm::mat4(1.0);

    Node* node_id = node;

    std::vector<Bone*> bones;
    std::vector<Node*> parents;

    while(node_id != nullptr)
    {
        Bone* bone = mesh->FindBone(node_id->name);

        if(bone != nullptr)
        {
            bones.push_back(bone);
            parents.push_back(node_id);

            node_id = bone->parent_node;
        }
        else
            node_id = nullptr;
    }


    for(int i = parents.size()-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        parent_transform *= glm::inverse(bones.at(i)->offset_matrix);
            parent_transform *= parents.at(i)->transformation;
        parent_transform *= (bones.at(i)->offset_matrix);
    }

}
```

If you have any questions about this or anything else regarding skeletal animation using ASSIMP please don't hesitate to ask me, you can contact me here or on my YouTube channel: RealityMultiplied

I'm going to start work on a tutorial series on how to do skeletal animation using ASSIMP right now, so I hope to have the first video up by tonight.

I hope to make this an easy to understand topic for those just beginning because it can seem daunting and just horrible overall.

EDIT:
So I started working on the tutorials, but I'm going through a lot tough shit in my life right now and I don't think I'm going to be able to finish them.
I hope they help at least a little bit, I'm sorry I couldn't do more.

http://realitymultiplied.blogspot.mx/